# Can we validate that the iOS apps on users phones are the same exact apps we submit to Apple?

Tags: ios, security

This is a bit of a security tinfoil-hat question:

Is there any sort of validation (checksum etc...) that our users are receiving the exact iOS apps we submit to Apple?

The thought experiment is: We are making a security iOS app.  Is it possible for Apple to change the apps we make to include backdoors, etc...  How can we validate that when our users download our apps, they are getting the same apps we made, devoid of any changes?

Regardless of the plausibility of this thought experiment, I'm just curious about the technology: Can we validate?

Comment: Can we get access to the actual "production" app to perform a checksum?

Comment: Couldn't you just download the app as a user and compare it to your submitted app?

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear.  I mean specifically for iOS.  Let me update question

Comment: Yes, its certainly a duplicate, thank you for pointing it out.